# c#/xml String.Contains does not return string properly when using a custom class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string

I'm trying to create a function where I can find an instance of a custom class in an array by searching for the base string. However, String.Contains does not seem to find the string anywhere in the array.

The array is set up by a seperate class which stores multiple Provider classes in an XML file.

```
<ContentProviders>
   <Providers>
       <Provider>
           <Name>Roblox (Epicgamers Redirect)</Name>
           <URL>http://epicgamers.xyz/asset/?id=</URL>
           <Icon>roblox.png</Icon>
       </Provider>
       <Provider>
           <Name>Roblox (Epicgamers Redirect Shortened)</Name>
           <URL>http://epiccc.xyz/asset/?id=</URL>
           <Icon>roblox.png</Icon>
       </Provider>
       <Provider>
           <Name>Finobe</Name>
           <URL>http://finobe.com/asset/?id=</URL>
           <Icon>finobe.png</Icon>
       </Provider>
       <Provider>
           <Name>Imgur</Name>
           <URL>http://i.imgur.com/</URL>
           <Icon>imgur.png</Icon>
       </Provider>
   </Providers>
</ContentProviders>
```

The array loads fine, however String.Contains doesn't seem to match the query with the URL, even if it exists.
If I use a URL like "http://i.imgur.com/TRGsjgo.png", it'll not find the base url, "http://i.imgur.com/", in the string.

Is there any way to fix this?

Code:

```
#region Content Provider Options
public class Provider
{
    public string Name;
    public string URL;
    public string Icon;
}

[XmlRoot("ContentProviders")]
public class ContentProviders
{
    [XmlArray("Providers")]
    public Provider[] Providers;
}

public class OnlineClothing
{
    public static Provider[] GetContentProviders(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentProviders));

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        ContentProviders providers;
        providers = (ContentProviders)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

        return providers.Providers;
    }

    public static Provider FindContentProviderByName(Provider[] providers, string query)
    {
        return providers.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Name.Contains(query));
    }
    
    public static Provider FindContentProviderByURL(Provider[] providers, string query)
    {
        return providers.SingleOrDefault(item => item.URL.Contains(query));
    }

    public static string GetURLForProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        return provider.URL;
    }

    public static string GetNameForProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        return provider.Name;
    }

    public static string GetIconNameForProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        return provider.Icon;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: "If I use a URL like "http://i.imgur.com/TRGsjgo.png", it'll not find the base url, "http://i.imgur.com/", in the string." - that's right, because in the query `item => item.URL.Contains(query)` you're checking whether "http://i.imgur.com/" contains "http://i.imgur.com/TRGsjgo.png", which it doesn't. If you want to check whether the *query* contains the *item URL* you need to change the way you're calling `Contains`. I'd argue that's a pretty unusual kind of query though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out while reading Jon Skeet's comment. I coded it wrong!

I needed to see if the query contained the provider URL, not if it contained the query.

```
public static Provider FindContentProviderByName(Provider[] providers, string query)
    {
        return providers.SingleOrDefault(item => query.Contains(item.Name));
    }
    
    public static Provider FindContentProviderByURL(Provider[] providers, string query)
    {
        return providers.SingleOrDefault(item => query.Contains(item.URL));
    }
```

Comment: Remember: if this solves your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I cannot because it says I can only accept my own answer after 2 days.